# Power spectrum, Welch method and window functions

Tags: signal-processing, python-3.7, window-functions, noise

I need to find power spectrum of a signal applying Welch method. Then using Chebyshev, Kaiser and Gauss windows, find the best window in terms of frequency separation.

I've wrote a function that produces noised sinusoidal signal and used the Welch method to this signal, also generated all of these three window functions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as sg

def sig_noise(f,snr,n):
    fs=1000
    dt=1/fs
    tk=n*dt
    A=1
    B=10**(-snr/20)
    t=np.arange(0,tk,dt)
    y=(np.random.rand(n)-0.5)
    z=A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)+B*y
    return z,t

[s,t]=sig_noise(140,-10,64)

f, Pxx_den = sg.welch(s,nperseg=64,noverlap=None) # Welch method, parameters are taken from book

plt.plot(f,Pxx_den)
plt.xlabel("Frequency")
plt.grid()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

chebyshev=sg.chebwin=(64,40) # Chebyshev window

kaiser=sg.kaiser(64,0) # Kaiser window

gauss=sg.gaussian(64,np.std((f,Pxx_den),ddof=0)) # Gauss window

# plots for check

plt.subplot(221)
plt.grid()
plt.title("Gauss")
plt.plot(gauss)
plt.subplot(222)
plt.grid()
plt.title("Chebyshev")
plt.plot(chebyshev)
plt.subplot(223)
plt.grid()
plt.title("Kaiser")
plt.plot(kaiser)

f, Pxx_den = sg.welch(s,nperseg=64,noverlap=None,window=chebyshev)
```

the last line of code doesn't work as I want to use for example chebyshev window. Unknown window type is what I get as the answer. Could somebody tell me where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with a extra `=` character on the following line:

```
chebyshev=sg.chebwin=(64,40) # Chebyshev window
#                  ^^^
#                  extra "=" character
```

This causes `chebyshev` to be equal to the tuple `(64,40)` rather than the intended array (following a similar approach as for your other windows). Later when given a tuple as windows argument, [`scipy.signal.welch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) tries to construct the window by calling [`scipy.signal.get_window`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.get_window.html) for a window type specified by the first element of the tuple. Obviously `64` (the first element of the tuple in your case) is not a valid window type.

So, the fix is to simply correct the typo:

```
chebyshev=sg.chebwin(64,40) # Chebyshev window
```

or alternatively call `welch` with an appropriately constructed tuple:

```
f, Pxx_den = sg.welch(s,nperseg=64,noverlap=None,window=('chebwin',40)
```